# Why am I unable to get phone numbers from my Contacts with the Cordova Contact API?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm building a phone app with with Steroids.js which is built on top of Phonegap. Right now, with the code below, I'm unable to retrieve phone numbers from my Contacts
Why am I unable to get phone numbers from my Contacts with the Cordova Contact API?

```
  <script>
  // Wait for Cordova to load
  //
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 // Cordova is ready
//
 function onDeviceReady() {
// find all contacts
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter=""; 
options.multiple=true;
var fields = ["*"];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);


}

// onSuccess: Get a snapshot of the current contacts
//
function onSuccess(contacts) {

for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {


for (var j=0; j<contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length; j++) {
                           alert(contacts[i].phoneNumbers[j].value );
                    }


 }  
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: did you add plugin to config?

Comment: add plugin to config? What do you mean?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/dbaq/cordova-plugin-contacts-phone-numbers to retrieve only the contacts with at least one phone number